# YouTube movies layout as one per line

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to switch YouTube layout to "one-per-line" layout instead of mesh/grid when I enter some channel (never mind which) and go to "Video" card? It would be so much more convenient to browse movies one by one NOT all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old design, there is a dropdown in the top right corner of the grid that says "Grid" and can be changed to "List".

In the new design, that button is missing, but the URL parameter `flow=list` still works. Here's an example use:

[`https://www.youtube.com/user/mugumogu/videos?flow=list`](https://www.youtube.com/user/mugumogu/videos?flow=list)

If you want to get back to the grid design, you can use the URL parameter `flow=grid`.